# Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 The multi-part identifier "E.EmployeeNumber" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      E.EmployeeNumber as ENumber,
      E.EmployeeFirstName,
      E.EmployeeLastName,
      T.EmployeeNumber as TNumber,
      sum(T.Amount) as TotalAmount
    FROM tblEmployee1 as E
    LEFT JOIN tblTransaction as T
      ON E.EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
    GROUP BY
      E.EmployeeNumber,
      T.EmployeeNumber,
      E.EmployeeFirstName,
      E.EmployeeLastName
) AS newTable
ORDER BY E.EmployeeNumber
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
> The multi-part identifier "E.EmployeeNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: `E.EmployeeNumber` should be `newTable.EmployeeNumber`.

Comment: No need for the alias in the ORDER BY.   Use  ORDER BY EmployeeNumber

Comment: Why do you have a derived table anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because is now out of scope from the object youre selecting from. You need to ORDER BY newTable.EmployeeNumber.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT E.EmployeeNumber AS ENumber
        ,E.EmployeeFirstName
        ,E.EmployeeLastName
        ,T.EmployeeNumber AS TNumber
        ,sum(T.Amount) AS TotalAmount
    FROM tblEmployee1 AS E   -- table alias E is right here
    LEFT JOIN tblTransaction AS T ON E.EmployeeNumber = T.EmployeeNumber
    GROUP BY E.EmployeeNumber
        ,T.EmployeeNumber
        ,E.EmployeeFirstName
        ,E.EmployeeLastName
    ) AS newTable   -- this is table alias newTable, whihc means E is now out of scope at this level. 
ORDER BY newTable.EmployeeNumber
```